# Select picker or select dropdown implementation in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking forward to implement select picker in react.js without using any third party library except bootstrap.

I have to style the option or dropdown menu as well which is not possible when I try to style it in html's select as it depends on the OS used and cannot be modified.

Comment: Please share the code that has been developed so far.

Comment: I got a solution. Please see m answer in this post.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really have to do with React. It can be achieved through the following:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

In react, you will just return the above in a render().

You will have to find a library to avoid OS specific rendering.

Read here on how to style it: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

I found a very flexible library to use select picker which may be useful for others as well.

Link : https://react-select.com